# Data Structure containing different kind of template in c++

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures

I write a program that read from text file.
I need to read the lines and do as follow the text.
for example:

> aaaa=3
>
> cccc=hi
>
> bbb=2
>
> ee=true
>
> print(bbb)

so my output will be:*2*

I use a template and write the "generic" function print.
but I'm looking for Data Structure that can save template from different type.

for example:

- my first organ contain variable **int** with key:aaaa value:3
- my second organ contain **string** key:cccc value:"hi"
- my Third organ contain **int** with key:bbb value:2
- my Fourth organ contain **bool** with key:ee value:true

I also need to be able to search them by key.
Any idea?

Comment: Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a heterogeneous link list in c or c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420744/how-to-create-a-heterogeneous-link-list-in-c-or-c)

Comment: How do you read the value from this data structure. Note an expression must have a compile-time fixed type.

Comment: the type is set in running time.. the program read from *text* file and follow the order in this file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just use an `unordered_map<string, string>`, the key is string and value is string, you can convert int, bool, string to string.

Comment: but I knoe the type only in running time *not* on compilation time.. so how can I know the convert?

Comment: @ShacharOren in the example, you only need to know what is bbb corresponding to. so you dont need to know 2 is type int, you only need to output with 2. And you said your input is a text file, so that is string, no need to know the thing after '=' is what type, consider them to be string.

Answer (score 0):

std::map from STL libraries is useful for doing heterogeneous mapping.

Comment: but is it OK that evert item in the MAP will be from different type?

Comment: once the std::map object is created, you have to maintain the same structure. But you might be able to use type casting provided if you can relate key and what type of value was stored in there.